# Correct way to parse timestamp with no timezone offset: 2017-01-06 16:57:05 UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. In Rails I have a timestamp from an external source that I don't have any control over:

   ```
   2017-01-06 16:57:05 UTC
   ```

   **Note:** There is no timezone offset in this timestamp.
2. I have the following in `application.rb`

   ```
   config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
   ```
3. When I print this time with a simple `puts` in the production logs I get:

   ```
   2017-01-06 10:57:05 +0000
   ```

   **Note:** If I do any parsing of this timestamp via `DateTime.parse(), Time.zone.parse(), or ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('UTC').parse()` I'm 6 hours off.
4. It should be:

   ```
   2017-01-06 10:57:05 -0600
   ```

   **Note:** see the correct timezone offset

So Rails has applied the `-0600` offset for Central Time to my original timestamp. In other words since there was no timezone offset provided with the original timestamp, `2017-01-06 16:57:05 UTC`, Rails has converted it to Central Time, `2017-01-06 10:57:05 +0000`, when it should be, `2017-01-06 10:57:05 -0600`

**How do I prevent this?**

So far I've come up with:

```
Time.zone.parse(my_time.to_s) - Time.zone.utc_offset
```

But that seems pretty fragile.

Comment: Have you tried: `Time.strptime(my_time.to_s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").in_time_zone`

Comment: @tibsar a slight modification: `Time.strptime(my_time.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z').in_time_zone` to make it work with my time format, but it still doesn't work. I'm still off by 6 hours. You can see this most clearly by dropping `.in_time_zone`

Comment: [This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) may be of help.

Comment: `puts Time.parse("2017-01-06 16:57:05 UTC").in_time_zone` returns `2017-01-06 10:57:05 -0600` on my system. Rails 4.0.4, Ruby 2.3.1. Which version do you use?